# What is the name of "bar code" like visualization for true/false data

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

What is the name of "bar code" like visualization for true/false data visualization?

Is possible to create in d3.js?

Example:
[image: http://infobeautiful4.s3.amazonaws.com/2016/02/facebook_boats-image-1.png]

**EDIT explanation**

I have different elements that can have diffent words like a tags. 
The words that an element can have, is 1 or all by a list of 120 differents words.

so, for each element i create a list of true/false to identify the presence or not that one of specific word.

For example, the possibile words are: [dog,cat,elephan,lion]

element 1: [dog, cat]

element 2: [dog, cat,elephant]

element 3: [cat, lion]

the true/false arrays based on [dog,cat,elephan,lion] are:

element 1: [1, 1, 0, 0]

element 2: [1, 1, 1, 0]

element 3: [0, 1, 0, 1]

to each element x i would create a visualizztion like the image that identify the presence or not that a specific word, where 1 there are a colored strip, where are 0 there are a blank space with a same size of colored strip.

Comment: Could you tell us more what exactly does it show? It seems to show more then two values (I can distinguish at least 5 distinct colours). Is it possible that you mention the rug plot: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126591/what-is-the-name-of-this-plot-using-vertical-lines-to-show-a-distribution ?

Comment: I added an explanation, but i think the "rug plot" is the more similar to my goal.